# VoIP ringtone not working

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, sinch

I'm using iOS version 9 and swift as well. I Can receive a call while the app is is active but when the app is closed or in the background, I have an issue, It only gets a notification, not a full ringtone (I'm using SinchService) but it's not working. I've added the VoIP certificate and it's valid

code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    sinch?.push().application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    sinch?.push().application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo)
}


func startManager() {
    let config = SinchService.config(withApplicationKey: VoiceManager.SinchKey, applicationSecret: VoiceManager.SinchSecret, environmentHost: VoiceManager.SinchHost).pushNotifications(with: SINAPSEnvironment.development)
    let sinch = SinchService.service(with: config)
    sinch?.delegate = self
    sinch?.callClient().delegate = self

    let push = Sinch.managedPush(with: SINAPSEnvironment.development)
    push?.delegate = self
    push?.setDesiredPushTypeAutomatically()

    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
    appDelegate.sinch = sinch
    appDelegate.push = push
}
```

// MARK: - SINCallClientDelegate

```
func client(_ client: SINCallClient!, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall!) {
    //show calling view
    let controller = UIViewController.currentViewController()
    VoiceCallingViewController.show(call: call, viewController: controller)
}


func client(_ client: SINCallClient!, localNotificationForIncomingCall call: SINCall!) -> SINLocalNotification! {
    let notification = SINLocalNotification()
    notification.alertAction! = LanguageManager.localizedString(key: "answer")
    notification.alertBody = "\(LanguageManager.localizedString(key: "incomming-call")) \(call.remoteUserId)"
    return notification
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not setting any sound in you localnotification method. add sound to notification